# How to get current location using google maps API in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to google maps API so i am wondering how do I get google maps to detect my current location when it is first loaded. Currently it can only display a marker of a hardcoded location but I want it to be my current location.

This is my current hardcoded location code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    LatLng test = new LatLng(33.8675,151.2070);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(test).title("test"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(test));
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37203191/5392118) answer please.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/). You need to use the [`LocationManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) to get the best provider and use it to get the location.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
    }
```

These services allow applications to obtain periodic updates of the device's geographical location, or to fire an application-specified [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) when the device enters the proximity of a given geographical location.

Check these related links:

- [get current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318324/get-current-location)
- [Finding Current Location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183859/finding-current-location-in-android)
- [Maps doesn't get current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801157/maps-doesnt-get-current-location)

Answer (score 0):

add this on onActivityResult

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(place.getLatLng().latitude,place.getLatLng().longitude);
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

and add this to onMapReady

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
```

and add 1 method

```
private OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            if(awal) {
                awal=false;
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Some questions for you. What is onActivityResult ? And how do i declare 'place' ?

Comment: According to the documentation `setOnMyLocationChangeListener` is deprecated. You should use FusedLocationProviderApi instead

Comment: onActivityResult is in your maps class.. the 'place' is declare using Lating

Answer (score -1):

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap = googleMap;


    if (!gMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);


            Toast.makeText(this, "Grant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return;


    }else {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            float la = (float) location.getLatitude() ;
            float lo = (float) location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(this, la+"______________"+lo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(la, lo);
            gMap.addMarker(new
                    MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint).title("Tutorialspoint.com"));
            gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(TutorialsPoint));
        }

}
```